# Cannot change directory after downloading a file through selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am working on this project that involves downloading a daily .csv. I have successfully written the code to download the .csv file through selenium. however, I am having trouble changing the directory when running the entire code.

The code in question is as follows:

```
download_purchases = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]')
download_purchases.click()

fp = os.path.expanduser('~')+'/Desktop/Export_Purchasing/CSV/'
os.chdir(fp)
files = [f for f in os.listdir(fp)]
```

When I run the whole syntax up unto this point, the files list comprehension produces an empty list. However, when i re run it (after having tried to run the whole code from the start), the list comprehension is able to detect the download .csv.

How can i make it so that the files are detected on the first pass? I tried quitting the driver with:

```
driver.quit()
```

but this didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the files are probably not downloaded by the time are hitting your last line: `files = [f for f in os.listdir(fp)]`. To test this you can add in a sleep like:

```
import time

download_purchases = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]')
download_purchases.click()

fp = os.path.expanduser('~')+'/Desktop/Export_Purchasing/CSV/'
os.chdir(fp)


print("Printed immediately.")
time.sleep(10)
files = [f for f in os.listdir(fp)]
```

If that works then you know that it is merely a timing issue and you can employ a more sophisticated solution to continue *after* the download is complete.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Yes you could, but that wouldn't highlight that it is a timing issue.